# pymysql cursor.execute() or cursor.rowcount returns 1 for multiple insert query execution

Tags: python, mysql, database, cursor, pymysql

Number of rows affected using `cursor.execute()` returns 1 when multiple insert query are executed. `cursor.rowcount` also returns 1 for multiple insert query execution. I have inserted 4 rows. But it returns 1. I have set the `client_flag= CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS|CLIENT.MULTI_RESULTS`.

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host, username, password, database, port, client_flag= CLIENT.MULTI_STATEMENTS|CLIENT.MULTI_RESULTS)
insert_statement= "INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('$SYS/publish/messages/received',0,1515580086025);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('$SYS/publish/messages/sent',0,1515580086025);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('$SYS/publish/messages/sent',3,1515580094997);
INSERT INTO demo VALUES ('$SYS/publish/messages/sent',4,1515580105983);"
cursor = connection.cursor()
row_count = cursor.execute(insert_statement)
print (row_count) -> #always prints 1 (but actually 4 rows are inserted as per insert_statement) 

print (cursor.rowcount) -> #always prints 1 (but actually 4 rows are inserted as per insert_statement)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: The result returned is not the number of rows in the table... (probably the number of rows inserted). You get what you're looking for by doing a SELECT * FROM query, and then counting the rows of _that_ query.

Comment: In database 4 rows are inserted but the rowcount and cursor.execute() gives count as 1. cursor.execute() would return the number of affected rows  http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html

Comment: Try calling cursor.executemany instead.